# Styledocco not rendering LESS, but applying the style

Tags: css, less

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966257/styledocco-output-docs-does-have-css-applied) but somewhat different.  The styles are applied but the less variables are not rendered.

[image: screenshot]

The .less file contents are [here](http://pastebin.com/94p3vNbi).

Any help getting the less aspect sorted would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
PJ

Comment: It just tries to interpreter your Less code as plain CSS (thus plain CSS properties are applied). Are your sure Styledocco should understand Less files directly? (i.e. first Less files have to be compiled to CSS, are you sure you set all necessary Styledocco flags/options? e.g. see https://jacobrask.github.io/styledocco/#usage).

Comment: The following from the docs made me think I didn't have to use the - - preprocessor flag, I'll test out your suggestion,  thank you. "StyleDocco will automatically compile any SASS, SCSS, Less or Stylus files before they are applied to the page"

Comment: Sadly I'm not getting any further by specifying a preprocessor using the following ```styledocco --preprocessor "/usr/local/bin/lessc" less/SO.less```

Comment: Interestingly, the css included in the html has the colors tranpiled they just don't appear in the doc.  http://pastebin.com/3CrSA2a7

Comment: ```<script type="text/preview">``` seems to be the culprit, if I remove that type attribute, it works as expected.

Comment: CORRECTION: ```<script type="text/preview">``` seems to be the culprit, if I remove that type attribute, it works sort of as expected but the formatting of the example goes outside it's boundry.